# Not able to perform sharding in a 3 node ArangoDB cluster

Tags: arangodb, sharding

I have deployed a 3 node cluster in my local (Using Docker) and created a collection (noOfShards = 3 and replicationFactor=1). However, when I create a document in one of the nodes, it is getting replicated in all the three nodes. I was expecting it to be distributed, based on my shard key.

I am not allowed to created a collection with replication factor of 0. My main intention is to shard the documents in my collection such that they are evenly distributed in the 3 nodes, based on the shard_key. I am really not concerned with the replication.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe what you did was Replication, which is not what you want to do for your requirement, what you should be doing is Sharding and this is very clearly highlighted in ArangoDB documentation:

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/architecture/data-sharding/

---

Creating a simple sharded collection

```
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> db._create("sharded_collection", { "numberOfShards": 3 });
```

---

In brief, it allows you to create collections that are sharded across your cluster which essentially meets your requirement.

The process is very straight forward

1. Setup an ArangoDB Cluster (which I believe you already know how)
2. Disable Replication or set it to a factor of 1
3. Create a Sharded collection (a simple tutorial can be found in the link above)

Moreover, I highly advise that you have a read from the Arango Learning Center for Clusters - this will help you alot in the long run.

https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-training-center/operations/

Comment: Hi, I had done exactly the same thing, but from the web interface of one of the coordinators. It doesn't allow me to create a collection without a replication factor, so I had set it to 1. But after creating of the collection, when I try to save a document through any one of the coordinators, it gets replicated in the other 2 also